# 501 Error using PUT with IIS

Tags: iis, http

When I attempt to write a file to the server using the PUT verb with WinHTTP like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384105(VS.85).aspx

My Windows 2003 server returns the header:

HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2009 11:31:14 GMT

I suspect that IIS needs to be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, IIS6 does not have PUT support out of the box, you need to enable the WebDAV extension.

There is a nice post explaining how to do that [here](http://whereofwecannotspeak.wordpress.com/2007/11/15/enabling-webdav-in-iis-for-http-put-support/).